# Unable to load native library from ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

I am trying to add prebuilt library following the steps given in documentation
CMakeList.txt:

```
add_library( mylib
             SHARED
             IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( mylib
                       PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       $libpath )

target_link_libraries(native-activity
                      android
                      mylib
                      log)
```

But I am getting error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.example.native_activity, PID: 32690
>                                                                                java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load native library
>   "/data/app/com.example.native_activity-1/lib/arm/libnative-activity.so":
>   dlopen failed: library "libselinux.so" not found

Even I extracted the apk and could not find the so file. Am I missing something

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that you are trying to link a shared library `mylib` to your `native-activity` shared library. In order to load the `mylib` library you have to package it into the .apk also. You only have to add this code to your native_module_path/build.gradle:

```
android {
    sourceSets{
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs  = ['path_to_mylib']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your library is in  `/data/app/com.example.native_activity-1/lib/arm/libnative-activity.so` and not  `data/app/com.example.native_activity-1/lib/arm/libnative-activity.so`? It seems you are specifying absolute path instead of relative.